# Programming ATmega328P over Pi UART

Tags: arduino, uart

I am developing a new product, and I need a simple way for users to be able to program an on-HAT ATmega328P using UART on the Pi. It looks like I have to use a reset pin, but I'm not confident about what that pin is. Here's a snippet of my schematic:

[image: Arduino to Rpi Connection]

My microcontroller is running at 3.3V. Can someone please help me find a solution to programming, ideally through the arduino IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with another Arduino; See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

This uses the `SPI` interface, and you should be able to write a program to do similar on the Pi.

The `Gertboard` includes a ATmega328, which can be programmed from the Pi (using `SPI`) The following is an extract from the Gertboard manual

> We are very grateful to Gordon Henderson, of Drogon Systems, for working out what needed to be done and providing the customized software. Using his system, you can use the Arduino IDE (Integrated Development Environment) on the Raspberry Pi to develop and upload code for the ATmega chip on the Gertboard. All the software needed, along with instructions, is available at
>   https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/gertboard/

The normal Arduino serial programming interface uses a bootloader on the Arduino. You could easily use the Pi serial to do similar, and use another pin to reset the ATmega328P. This, of course, assumes you are using a chip with a bootloader.

The Arduino Mini requires an external serial for programming; See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMini Most people use a USB-serial interface to do the programming, but the Pi could be used.